# Web services intellij idea (HelloWorld example is not working)

Tags: web-services, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create simple WebServices project using Intellij Idea 12 IDE (Glassfish 4.0.0 server, JDK 1.7.0_45)
And have a couple of troubles.

First of all, I cannot expose or unexpose my default class HelloWorld. I just do not have this button (Expose Class as Web Service) in menu 'Web Services' or even in the tab 'tools'.
Somewhere I've found that ALT+ENTER could help me, but it did not. There were no signs of that functionality too.

However, as you probably know, it is not extremely important in this test (HelloWorld) example to expose the class (it is exposed by default) and I still tried to launch my simple solution. But it does not work.
It shows just blank window in browser (path: localhost:8080/jax_ws_server or smth like this). When I intentionally tried to change this path to string (I've changed it not only in browser url-string, but also in Artifacts settings) 'localhost:8080/services/HelloWorld', which I have found in the configuration file 'sun-jaxws.xml', It just shows 404 error in a browser.

I use this tutorial:
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_a_simple_JaxWS_WebService

What can I do to solve this problems? Thank you for every answer!